# Create subfolders and move files into their respective subfolder

Tags: directory, command-prompt

Is it possible using command prompt to read the file list in a given directory, such as:

```
C:\Users\My Documents\Folder1\
```

Which contains the following files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
...
```

Create a subfolder for each file, named for each file name

```
C:\Users\My Documents\Folder1\file1\
C:\Users\My Documents\Folder1\file2\
C:\Users\My Documents\Folder1\file3\
...
```

Then move (or copy) all the files into their respective subfolder? The end result would be files existing at:

```
C:\Users\My Documents\Folder1\file1\file1.txt
C:\Users\My Documents\Folder1\file2\file2.txt
C:\Users\My Documents\Folder1\file3\file3.txt
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i ended up using:

```
@ECHO OFF

for %%F IN (*) do (
    echo Copy local file: %%F
    mkdir "%CD%\%%~nF\"
    copy /Y "%%F" "%CD%\%%~nF\%%F"
)

rd /s /q "%CD%\MoveToSubFolders"

ECHO.Done
```

Answer (score -1):

i hope this may help you

```
md folder1
for i=1 to numberOfSubfolders
 md folder+i
 cd folder+i
 create filer+i
 cd..

next
```